# map not loading because venure service version is not supported

Tags: here-api

I'm getting an error that venue service version 1 is no longer supported.
I'm using version 3.1.3.5 of the javascript version of Here.
Is there a newer version that I need to switch to?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version for Maps API for JavaScript is 3.1.30.16. We would suggest you to upgrade the version.

For more help on Indoor Maps with JS API, please refer to the updated guide at https://developer.here.com/documentation/indoor-map/user_guide/topics/indoor-jsapi.html

You can also refer to an example at https://jsfiddle.net/y1wq98hm/

```
     venuesService.loadVenue('7348').then((venue) => {
    // add Indoor Maps data to the Indoor Maps provider
    venuesProvider.addVenue(venue);
    venuesProvider.setActiveVenue(venue);

    // create a tile layer for the Indoor Maps provider
    map.addLayer(new H.map.layer.TileLayer(venuesProvider));

    // Set center of the map view to the center of the venue
    map.setCenter(venue.getCenter());

    // optionally select a different level
    venue.setActiveDrawing(7880);

    // create a level control
    const levelControl = new H.venues.ui.LevelControl(venue);
    ui.addControl('level-control', levelControl);

    // create a drawing control:
    const drawingControl = new H.venues.ui.DrawingControl(venue);
    ui.addControl('drawing-control', drawingControl);
  });
}
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Step 2: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'), defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  zoom: 18,
  center: { lat: 47.452353, lng: 8.562455 },
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});

// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

// Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Step 4: create the default UI component, for displaying bubbles
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Step 5: add the Indoor Map
addVenueToMap(map);
```